# How to configure a systemd service that uses D-Bus?

Tags: environment-variables, systemd, dbus

I wrote a script that sends notifications. The script calls `notify-send` to do this, and `notify-send` requires a D-Bus environment variable to work: `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

When I run my script from the terminal, it produces notifications just fine. But I use systemd to run my script whenever I log in, and when systemd runs the script, it no longer produces notifications. This is because systemd starts my script with a clean environment --- and than means the D-Bus environment variable is missing.

On Arch Linux, I was able to add this to the script's unit file:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
Requires=dbus-setenv.service
```

With this config, systemd started my script when D-Bus was ready, and passed the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable to my script.

Now I'm on Ubuntu, but that configuration doesn't seem to be working. I'm wondering: what is the recommended way to do this under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment ... I am using this in another script to change the wallpaper with `cron`:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
user=$(whoami)

fl=$(find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user "$user" -name environ -print -quit)
for i in {1..5}
do
  fl=$(find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user "$user" -name environ -newer "$fl" -print -quit)
done

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS "$fl" | cut -d= -f2-)
```